# Рубашка -- единственное исконно-русское название предмета одежды?

Tags: лексикон, заимствования, словарь

Правда ли, что *рубашка* (от *рубить*) -- более-менее единственный элемент **современной** одежды или обуви, называющимся исконно русским словом? Вот тут список некоторых из основных слов, все остальные предметы которого имеют заимствованные названия:

*рубашка, пальто, шуба, шапка, кепка, пиджак, костюм, сюртук, куртка, кофта, свитер, джемпер, пуловер, майка, трусы, штаны, брюки, джинсы, юбка, чулки, ботинки, туфли*

Почему так велика доля заимствованной лексики? Является ли это феноменом русского языка?

Comment: Words for those fashion items are borrowed because the items themselves are borrowed. Latin words for trousers (*braca*) and tunic (*tunica*) are loanwords as well, and for the same reason too.

Comment: конечно слово само не приходит в язык, оно нужно в языке дня обозначения предмета или явления, и почему вас удивляет что только одно слово русское, вы загляните в историю, как россия жила, как территория менялась, как народ менялся, как жизнь менялась. изза климата и огромных территорий в россии все подвижки прогресса всегда шли медленнее чем в европе где всё ближе и дороги лучше) это хорошо что дошло а погло ведь и недойти

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Большое количество заимствованных слов, обозначающих предметы одежды, неудивительно, если вспомнить, что мода в Россию, по крайней мере, с петровских времен, приходила из-за границы. Этим же объясняется и вытеснение заимствованными формами русских слов: Если одеваться по иностранной моде престижно, то Вы скорее наденете голландские *брюки*, чем русские *портки*.

Тем не менее, *рубашка* - далеко не единственный предмет одежды, называемый русским словом. На ум приходят **платье**, **сорочка**, **дублёнка**; части одежды, например, **рукав**, **воротник**. Кроме того, из приведенных Вами слов некоторые, например, *шуба*, используются в славянских языках с глубокой древности, будучи, таким образом, старше и русского этноса, и современного русского языка. Так что они вполне могут считаться исконно-русскими.

Comment: +1, ещё добавлю _балахон_, _пояс_, _ремень_, _пряжка_ и _носок_; а из _обуви_: _сапог_ и _каблук_.

Comment: @H.Zeta: *плащ, подтяжки, толстовка, перчатки, рукавицы, варежки*.

Comment: и + платок, лапти, косынка

Comment: @Quassnoi  [_варежки_](http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-1634.htm) это варяжские рукавицы, слово русское, но корень-то все равно заимствованный?

Comment: @JMSTER: of course.

Comment: @Quassnoi: Может ли "толстовка" быть исконно русским словом, если это неологизм начала XX века, образованный от фамилии?

Comment: @vleseg: of course it is.

Comment: @Vleseg Проблематично само понятие "исконно-русское" в вопросе. В моем ответе я негласно решил считать за исконно-русские слова те, которые сравнимы по возрасту или старше русского языка и до его формирования использовались в его предках и родственных языках. При таком определении получается, что "толстовка" - действительно не исконно-русское слово. Но нельзя забывать, что живой язык постоянно изменяется, в нем образуются новые слова. Поэтому говорить об "исконности" того или иного слова некорректно, я бы скорее разделял корни на славянские и неславянские.

Comment: @Anton: I'd consider a word native Russian if it has been formed in Russian (or any of its ancestors) from a loaned root with a serious change in meaning. *Халат* is a loanword; *халатность* is not. In the same way, meanings of *варежка* and *толстовка* have absolutely nothing in common with "truthful" or "fat", that's why I consider those words native Russian.

Answer (score -1):

Рубашка - уменьшительное от рубаха, роба. Возможно, происходит вовсе не от "рубить" а от "робить" (работать), но может быть даже из библейского лексикона.

> Почему так велика доля заимствованной лексики? Является ли это феноменом русского языка?

Если коротко - да, несомненно. Не феномен, а факт. Вот, библейский лексикон в том числе. (Возможно есть языки и с бОльшим процентом импорта... не знаю.)

Comment: Спасибо за -1, вы поняли мой ответ правильно.

Comment: и шуба тоже от тюркского корня. Увы.